# What is the meaning of "くうとうめえから"

Tags: meaning, colloquial-language

I found this sentence in a book :

> この魚もうたべあきただものね。だからあんたにやるよ。色は青いけれど刺身にしてくうとうめえから。

I didn't understand the last part of `くうとうめえから`

Comment: Are you sure you transcribed the first sentence correctly? It's odd to have だ right after a verb (たべあきた)

Comment: yes yes, it's the same as in the book, I searched about that だ, it's actually だもの　and it indicates the reason (of giving the fish.)

Comment: @oals is right in that it is odd because it certainly is not standard. This sentence seems to be a part of conversation, and these expressions used here indicates that the speaker has a provincial accent and is not very well-educated.

Comment: @Yosh That is true the sentence is a part of a conversation between an old fisherman from Okinawa and a traveler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be 刺身にして食うと[美味い]{うまい}から

*'If you eat it as sashimi, it's delicious'*